# How to use an enumeration on my view model on a data trigger in my view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I have an enumeration on my view model:

```
namespace MyApplication.ViewModels
{
    public enum MyEnum {value1, value2, value3}

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        //All the code of my view model.
    }
}
```

In my view I have this data trigger:

In the header:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApplication.ViewModels"
```

In the style of the checkBox to use a data trigger:

```
<CheckBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ucPrincipal, Path=DataContext.MyViewModelProperty}" Value="{vm:MyEnum.Value1}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</CheckBox.Style>
```

But in the trigger, when I try to access to the vm variables, I don't have access to the enumeration.

Is it possible to access to the enumeration from the view? Or how could I achieve this?

Thank so much.

Comment: try `{x:Static vm:MyEnum.Value1}`

Comment: Or use `int` value of your enum

Comment: and if your `enum` is inside of a class then use `{x:Static vm:MyViewModel+MyEnum.Value1}`